# Module only generating artifact when DTO implements a certain interface

Tags: java, maven, gwt, legacy

*context: Java; GWT; Maven;

I have a DTO class that was always implementing an interface called OriginalI and OriginalI is extending IsSerializable. There is NO more code in OriginalI interface.
DTO class is on a module and OriginalI interface is on another. There is no problem with doing clean-install both modules

I wanted to make some changes to the code so I put DTO class implementing SecondI interface which in turn is extending OriginalI interface. When I do this I CANNOT make clean-install, there is a error which only says that the maven command failed with status code 1. There is no more error message and I even tried with flags -X and -e.

What could be happening? How can I solve or find/understand the root of the problem?

Thank you.

I tried putting the flags -X and -e in mvn command to see more detailed error but it says the same (failed with status 1).

I tried making DTO class NOT implementing nothing at all and it does not work.
I tried making DTO class implementing SecondI which in turn is extending IsSerializable and it does not work.

Update: ok, i cannot even make the DTO class extend another class in any type. This is a restriction hidden somewhere and i'm having trouble finfing it. I saw we use AbstractMojo and goals for some maven plugins but couldn't pinpoint the exact code that's causing this.